# Unique constraint violation found when placing order in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, checkout-page, unique-constraint

***I am getting the error of Unique constraint violation found when placing an order in the Magento 2.***

> When I checked the log file it shows like this -> main.INFO:
>   Reference to undeclared plugin with name
>   'stockedProductsFilterPlugin'. [] [].

***I followed this article to solve this :***

> https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-unique-constraint-violation-found-magento-2-checkout-after-migration/.

***It worked for the first time but after that, it again shows Unique constraint violation found. Please help me to solve this.***

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is that my DB is not properly imported. There is some broken reference in that. I fixed it and it is working fine now.

Comment: I also have problem in db while moving website to another domain. Some table lost primary key. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @Kowsigan can you share me the way to fix this?

Comment: this doesnt seem to be an answer - just a status update

Answer (score 2):

I have fetched same issue after migration. May be the issue related sequence table in database.

Update sequence_order_0  and sequence_order_1 table, set primary key sequence_value and insert two or three number entry.

Comment: I tried your solution but it's not resolved, Can you guide me

Comment: Check your all sequence table.   "sequence_order_0" , "sequence_order_1", In that table sequence_value must be defined autoincrment primary key.

Comment: I make it all about 24 table of sequence_order_ but still error :(

Comment: First execute reindex command, clean cache, Remove cart item and add to cart product.

And check again

Comment: add two to three values in sequence_order_0, and sequence_order_1 table.

Comment: I have 24 table of prefix sequence_order_, then I tried to set unique value to all tables then insert the sample data of 5 rows. then I re-compile magento + flush cache but it still error when I try to cancel an order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121213/discussion-between-shinesh-and-huykon225).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sequence_order_XX` table AUTO_INCREMENT value. I've had some orders in `sales_order` table already. After updating the `sequence_order_XX` AUTO_INCREMENT value problem disappeared.