# Unique constraint violation found during checkout magento 2.3.7

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am getting "Unique constraint Violation error: message when i try to place order using Paytm.
Place order works fine with Payu and Paypal method. But gives violation error on selecting paytm.  https://prnt.sc/1s58lfz
What is the issue ? How can i resolve it?

Comment: check log file and also in console log

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Placing an order with quote_id 577322 is failed: Unique constraint violation found [] []

this error is coming in debug.log

Answer (score 0):

did you moved the site from another host or migrated from the previous version?

Please check the database! Maybe the import is not successful.

The same issue here was fixed by importing the database again!
[Unique constraint violation found when placing order in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286909/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-placing-order-in-magento-2)

Comment: Data migration is done from 2.1 to 2.3.

Comment: did you try to reindex and cache clean?
You are using one-page checkout I think, is it compatible with your current Magento version 2.3.x?

Comment: Please check the table "sequence_order_1" for column "sequence_value" is set to auto_increment

Comment: The problem is coming with only Paytm payment and not with other? why so? Do you think its an issue from magento's end or payment method?

Comment: I hope you are talking about this website https://www.chaichai.in/
did you disable the one-page checkout?
I think this issue may be coming from one page checkout module

Comment: website is https://demo.chaichai.in/

Comment: not able to access the website 
getting this error
/home/chaichai7/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 975

Comment: you can try this solution
https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-unique-constraint-violation-found-magento-2-checkout-after-migration/

The same cart id seems used again
try to checkout in incognito mode or new account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129800/discussion-between-chandirasekaranid-and-nafsss).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this I've found a viable workaround. Or at least one that worked for me on Magento 2.3.5.

1. Install this: https://github.com/boolfly/sales-sequence
2. In the admin go to Sales > Sales Sequence
3. Add a custom prefix to all of your entity types
4. Just to be safe, reindex and dump the cache
5. You now have unique fields for all new orders, invoices etc.

Good to go! *(Or at least I was.)*

Hope it helps someone.